# FBSDKAppInviteDialog is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, fbsdksharekit

I am Implementing app to invite friend

But it gives me below error

[image]

Comment: Add the error in a text format, so that it can be searched as well.

Comment: [![Facebook had made major changes to there developer offerings. Which includes AppInvites ,Native Like Button, Comment Mirroring etc ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYdGi.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYdGi.png)
[Which includes AppInvites ,Native Like Button, Comment Mirroring etc](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OLD method is deprecated

Document : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKAppInviteDialog/

New Method :

```
+ (instancetype)
showFromViewController: (UIViewController *)viewController
withContent:    (FBSDKAppInviteContent *)content
delegate:   (id<FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate>)delegate;
```

Declared In: FBSDKAppInviteDialog.h

```
showWithContent:delegate:
```

---

```
+ (instancetype)
showWithContent:    (FBSDKAppInviteContent *)content
delegate:   (id<FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate>)delegate
__attribute__((deprecated("use showFromViewController: withContent:delegate: instead")));
Declared In: FBSDKAppInviteDialog.h
```

Comment: i got solution of deprecated warning BUT i still get bottom left error as per show Questions image

Comment: @imjaydeep Welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

App invites are no longer supported by Facebook, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/11/07/changes-developer-offerings/).

*App Invites will no longer be supported starting with Facebook SDK version 4.28 and above. Previous versions of the SDK can still access App Invites, but starting 2/6, App Invites will no longer be supported.*